# How can I change system font values for specific applications?

Tags: gnome, fonts, 21.04

As the title asks, I'm wondering if it's possible to change an application's understanding of which fonts are used for the Interface Text and Document Text values in Gnome.

Context:

I generally use [TablePlus](https://tableplus.com/linux) when working with SQL Server, PostgreSQL, and MySQL databases. It's a closed-source application, which means I do not have the luxury of reaching into the code and changing the fonts that are used within the application.

Because it is a SQL editor, monospaced fonts are the only realistic option to use. An `l` must look like an `l` and not a `1`. I can get the application to use monospaced fonts in the interface if I change the Interface Text and Document Text values in GNOME Tweaks, but I do not want to make *everything* on Ubuntu monospaced, as that's overkill (besides, I *like* the Ubuntu font).

On the left is what I have, and on the right is what I want to see (in the editor and results spaces only, but one battle at a time):

[image: Table Plus Minus the Preferences]

So, if the application is reading the Interface Text and Document Text values from the GNOME interface settings, I would like to have the application use a font of my choosing. There is [an outstanding issue](https://github.com/TablePlus/TablePlus-Linux/issues/76) requesting the ability to change the font settings within the application already, but it has not been implemented.

Comment: Can you trick it into thinking your home directory is elsewhere by running it as `HOME=/some/other/directory tableplus` (or whatever the actual command is)?

Comment: @muru looks like I can do that, yes. The application will recreate its local cache files in the directory I specify and load. Would it be possible to have a copy of the Gnome font settings in that faux directory with the monospaced fonts?

Comment: I think so. Your original file would be in `~/.config/dconf`. You can make the change in Tweaks, then copy it to the fake home and then change back in Tweaks.

Comment: @muru well, I'll be a son of a gun. This works! ありがとうございました! ‍♂️

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you check if just setting `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` (instead of `HOME`) is enough?

Comment: Tested and failed. `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` does not seem to carry the same range of settings as `HOME`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to make it look for the configuration in a different location than the usual place.

With a reasonably well-behaved modern tool, configuration should be in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` (defaults to `$HOME/.config`), so setting `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` to some other directory and keeping a copy of your desired configuration there should work (this should be true of GNOME Tweaks itself). However, not everything supports the [XDG specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) yet, and especially in the case of proprietary applications, you might need to be more blunt and set `HOME` instead. (Particularly bad applications may even try to get `HOME` from NSS, and ignore the `HOME` environment variable.)

The GSettings/DConf configuration is stored in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/dconf` (`~/.config/dconf` by default). You can change the font, then copy that directory somewhere else, and run the offending application with `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` (or `HOME`, if it's not well-behaved) set to point there.